# Which one is better WSO2 ESB and WSO2 EI for integration

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I know that WSO2 ESB is one of product of WSO2 EI platform.
But I need to connect oracle database and execute some sample queries, I cannot find this feature from WSO2 ESB, but WSO EI has that features

Please refer below Questions:

- What if i use WSO2 EI instead of WSO2 ESB for integrate our systems and subsystems in productino usages ?
- Which one is better to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSO2 EI is nothing more than a collection of profiles such as WSO2 ESB, WSO2 Message Broker etc. You can use WSO2 EI without any problem because WSO2 ESB is not released separately anymore. Download EI and start the ESB profile by going to [EI-HOME]/bin/integrator.sh.

Comment: Okay Thanks for quick response